# How to express a likelihood function for the following regression?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, conditional-probability, likelihood, conditional-distribution

I have asked this question in entirely different forms a number of times on StackExchange, to no avail. Between each question, I investigated the literature thoroughly, but I have yet to find a solution to my problem. Suppose, we have the system of equations:
\begin{equation}
Y_t=\beta X_{t-1} +u_t\\
X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation}
for $t=1,\cdots,T$. Assuming that $Y_1\mid X_0=x_0,\cdots,Y_T\mid X_{T-1}=x_{T-1}$ are independent I am interested in expressing a likelihood function, such that the likelihood function would ultimately be of the form
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\beta)=f(y_1\mid x_0)\times f(y_2\mid x_0,x_1)\times f(y_T\mid x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_{T-1}) 
\end{equation}

A) Is the above correct?

B) If not, and given the system of equations mentioned and the likelihood function of interest, what is an alternative?

Comment: 1st: the likelihood of an AR process is not conditional only on the initial value. Rather, for any X_t, its contribution to the likelihood is conditional only on X_{t-1}. Second, can you help us understand why you want dependence on all prior terms, when your defining equations depend only on the previous term?

Comment: @JohnMadden Your remark about the AR process is correct. The joint likelihood function is expressed using the chain rule of probability and each $X_t$, it is indeed conditioned only on $X_{t-1}$ (assuming you are referring to an AR(1)). With regards to the second remark, the reason I want it conditioned on the entire past information is due to an assumption that I am imposing in the paper. But for now, let us suppose dependence only on the previous term as you had stated, and that the likelihood function is adjusted to reflect this. Would that expression then be correct?

Comment: What I'm not following is that you want a likelihood for $Y_t$ so it seems to me like you only need the first equation. How does the second equation help ?

Comment: @mlofton Yes you are correct that if I am expressing the likelihood fr $Y_t$, the second equation seems unnecessary. However, for the sake of completeness, I expressed the dynamics of the entire model.

Comment: Hi: then, the likeihood that you have is fine, except, as John Madden said, you don't need the previous terms, only the immediately previous lagged term. So, you can remove all the other terms and the likelihood simplifies. In the Kalman filter framework, they call that the likelihood decompostion. See Andrew Harvey's blue book ( title of which escapes me but it's covers the kalman filter and structural modelling ) for the details of the likelihood decomposition.